# prolog sorting a list based on the sublist of each element

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment in prolog with lists and before anything else i have to order the list based on the second element.
The list is a code, for example, this
`[(a,[1,0]),(x,[0,0]),(d,[0,1])]` has to be `[(x,[0,0]),(d,[0,1]),(a,[1,0])]` because it's sorted based on the binary code. Right now I'm just using sort/2 but it sorts the list based on the first caracter like this `[(a,[1,0]),(d,[0,1]),(x,[0,0])]` which is wrong.
I'm inexperienced in prolog so maybe there's a way to do this with sort/2 and I don't know it?

I've also seen another question with this suggestion:

```
compareAvg(X,  [_,A1], [_,A2]) :- compare(X, A1, A2).

then you can call

predsort(compareAvg, [[1,2],[3,1],[5,3]],X).
```

but my list has a varying size so I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Should code lists be interpreted as numbers or lists? I mean: for example, sorting the list ```[(a,[1]),(x,[1,1]),(d,[0,1,0])]```, you want to get ```[(a,[1]),(d,[0,1,0]),(x,[1,1])]``` (where the code lists ```[1]```, ```[0,1,0]``` and ```[1,1]``` are interpreted as the numbers ```1```, ```2``` and ```3```) or ```[(d,[0,1,0]),(a,[1]),(x,[1,1])]``` (where the code lists represent themselves)? If the code lists should be taken as numbers, then you will need to convert then to numbers before sorting.

Comment: @slago does it make a difference? The greatest number would be achieved by sorting the lists anyway

Comment: @coder Of course it does: ```[1]``` is ***numerically*** less than ```[0,1,0]``` (since number 1 is less than number 2), but ```[0,1,0]``` is ***lexicographically*** less than ```[1]``` (since the head of the first list, 0, is less than the head of the second list, 1).

Comment: @coder Notice that ```?- sort(2,@=<,[(a,[1,0,1]),(x,[1]),(d,[0,1,0])], Sorted).``` produces ```Sorted = [(d,[0,1,0]),(x,[1]),(a,[1,0,1])]```, not ```Sorted = [(x,[1]),(d,[0,1, 0]),(a,[1,0,1])]``` (that would be produced if code lists are interpreted as numbers).

Comment: @slago, yeah you're right ! basically in my solution i assumed lists would be of same length were it works right i think..

Comment: hey! I wanted to sort it lexicographically so the answer suggesting sort/4 worked, thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`sort/4`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4) predicate:

```
sort(2, @=<, Input, SortedOutput).
```

Examples:

```
?- sort(2, @=<, [(a,[1,0]),(x,[0,0]),(d,[0,1])], Sorted).
Sorted = [(x, [0, 0]),  (d, [0, 1]),  (a, [1, 0])].

?- sort(2, @=<, [(a,[1,0,1]),(x,[0,0,1]),(d,[0,1,0])], Sorted).
Sorted = [(x, [0, 0, 1]),  (d, [0, 1, 0]),  (a, [1, 0, 1])].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
compareAvg(X,  [_,A1 | _], [_,A2 | _]) :- compare(X, A1, A2).
```